# SQL Query Builder - Grouping and Ordering (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to get a set of results from one of my tables to output to a chart. The chart needs to show "the number of concerns for each month, for this academic year (1st Sept 2018 to 31st August 2018)".

The returned result *should* look something like:

```
| month     | total |
|-----------|-------|
| September | 15    |
| October   | 23    |
| December  | 24    |
| January   | 438   |
```

The problem comes when I try and group the month together; i get an incorrect count value.

The query I currently have is:-

```php
    // Returns 2018-09-01 00:00:00
        $start = Carbon::createMidnightDate(Carbon::now()->subMonths(8)->year, 9, 1);
    // Gets current date
        $end = Carbon::now();

        $concerns = DB::table('concerns')
            ->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month, count(*) as total, created_at'))
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->groupBy('created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
            ->get()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
                return [$item->month => $item->total];
          });
```

However this returns me:-

```
| month     | total |
|-----------|-------|
| September | 1     |
| October   | 1     |
| December  | 1     |
| January   | 1     |
```

It's clearly not adding all of the individual values together because of the grouping of the `created_at` date, however excluding it prevents me from ordering it due to the MySQL `only_full_group_by` mode.

Any advice would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `created_at` in your `SELECT` to get the results you want. You should be able to just simplify the query to:

```
$concerns = DB::table('concerns')
    ->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month, count(*) as total'))
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
```

Note this assumes there are 12 months or less between `$start` and `$end`. Otherwise you will need to group by `YEAR(created_at)` as well.

If you are running MySQL 8, or [`only_full_group_by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is enabled, you will need to go to more pain to get a valid query to meet the requirements for `GROUP BY`. This should work:

```
$concerns = DB::table('concerns')
    ->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, YEAR(created_at) AS year, count(*) as total'))
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
    ->groupBy('year', 'month')
    ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
    ->orderByRaw("MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ', month, ' ', year), '%e %M %y')) asc")
```

I've made a demo of that query working on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eff6ca9eda7f835e0335604466df6665)

Comment: Nice one. Is there any reason to have the 2 `orderBy` instead of a single `orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`?

Comment: @Mozammil that would work as even though `created_at` would be an arbitrary value for each group, it would increase with each month.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get the CONCAT() bit of that second one to work properly -

PHPStorm just highlights it as a syntax error but can't see why

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add I'd tried orderByRaw() - this is how it looks: [link](https://pasteboard.co/HWRu0Cc.png)

Comment: @NickDavies see my edit, orderByRaw only has one parameter, you need to combine the `asc` into the string as I have done

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nick - Still the same unfortunately. [error](https://pasteboard.co/HWRxHHP.png)

Comment: @NickDavies Sorry, I'm an idiot. The outer quotes on the string should be double quotes. See my new edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186856/discussion-between-nick-davies-and-nick).